# Laravel image in public/images gives 404 error on Forge live site, but fine on localhost

Tags: laravel, assets, .env

I have a JPG image in my images folder inside `/public`. On my localhost dev app (Laragon) this is fine and the image is displayed with the following code:

```
<div class="panel-heading"><img  style="float:left" width="20" height="20" src=" {{ asset('images/infobubble.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive" alt="feature img">&nbsp; Your Upgrade Options</div>
```

However, I get a 404 error when deployed to my Forge/DigitalOcean website.

Other images used throughout my app on other pages are displayed as expected. I have read many posts related to similar issues but have yet to find a solution.

I can see the file on the site, it's there, but can't access it via a browser. I've renamed it and changed from PNG to JPG to try to force it to show (in case I had a reference or typo I couldn't see). Whether in the page or copying the image link and trying to view it directly, I get 404.

I read some suggestions about changing my `.ENV` file on my deployed version, so I added

```
ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

to by live site's `.ENV` file, to no avail. I also cleared `config` and `cache`.

It feels like a permission issue or maybe I'm missing some nuance with the path or how `asset()` is handled.

Any suggestions as to how to tackle this?

Comment: have you checked the permissions on this particular image?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as all the other workign images: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge  13438 May 17 07:49  Infobubble.jpg`